# Entity framework am I using to SQL CE or SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm using EF with 2 databases - with SQL CE and SQL Server.

Is there a way to know which connection type is used at runtime? I mean, if I have only ObjectContext in some place (already initialized with some connection string), can I get the database type from it (is it Compact or SQL Server at the moment)?

Thanks

Comment: The point of EF4 (or one of at least) is to abstract this information.  If you are able to deduce from the context which database is in use, I'd highly recommend not forming any logic from it?

Comment: thanks, I now about that. There's just a Timeout setter depending on that. And I hope to rework it either. But I need a little fix for now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the [Connection Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.connection.aspx), which should return an [EntityConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.aspx); from there you must check its [StoreConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.storeconnection.aspx) which will be the "real" database connection.

From there, you can either check the [ConnectionString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.connectionstring.aspx), which will tell you the provider, or simply check the type of the provider connection itself with `is` or `GetType`. If it's SQL Server it will be a `SqlConnection`, and if it's SQL CE it will be a `SqlCeConnection`.

This looks like an ugly hack because it is; if you're looking for a way to do this *without* an ugly hack, don't bother - the `ObjectContext` is explicitly designed *not* to leak any information about the connection unless you know exactly what to ask for.  By contrast, here's all the hoops you would have to jump through to check it via the app config:

```
static string GetProviderName(ObjectContext context)
{
    string entityConnectionString = GetEntityConnectionString(context);
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(entityConnectionString) ?
        GetProviderConnectionString(entityConnectionString) : null;
}

static string GetEntityConnectionString(ObjectContext context)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(context.Connection.ConnectionString,
        @"name=(?<name>[^;]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    string connectionStringName = match.Success ?
        match.Groups["name"].Value : null;
    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;
}

static string GetProviderConnectionString(string entityConnectionString)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(entityConnectionString,
        @"provider=(?<provider>[^;]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    return match.Success ? match.Groups["provider"].Value : null;
}
```

Once any solution starts to involve regexes, I tend to look for a straighter path, and in this case, that's the type casting you say you'd prefer not to use. Pick your poison.

Be careful how you use either of the above approaches. EF4 is designed around *persistence ignorance* and you should be trying to avoid any logic that's specific to the connection type, because you really have no idea how it will be configured (maybe tomorrow it will be an Oracle connection). I believe that the provider-specific code resides mainly in the [QueryProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.queryprovider.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and reminder about persistence ignorance - everything'll be ok with that :) ConnectionString is no use - in my case it's just "name=SomeSpecificName". I'm now using your second proposal, but the type of the `Connection` property is `DbConnection` and I'm now casting it to `EntityConnection`, like: `((EntityConnection)(Connection)).StoreConnection is SqlCeConnection`. That's the thing I'm trying to get rid of, if there's another way :)